# How to program a program that add the sum up in an array using for loops in php

Tags: php, for-loop

Using for loops, write a single program that finds the average of the following integers.  In the same program, find the sum of every other number in the array.

```
$num = [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81];
```

This is the code that I have:

```
<?php
        $sum1 = 0;
        $sum2 = 0;
        $num = array(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81); 
        for ($k = 0, $i = 0; $i < 9; $i++, $k = $k + 2) {
            $sum1 = $num{$k} + $sum1;
            $sum2 = $num{$i} + $sum2;
        }
        echo "Sum is " . $sum2 . "  ";
        echo "Sum of offset is " . $sum1;
        ?>
```

Comment: What is the error or question? Code seems fine.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Nitin The `for` syntax is incorrect, he accesses keys he shouldn't. (If `$i` gets to `8`, `$k` will be `16` and there is no `$num[16]` - just an example).

Comment: @ccKep you are right. should have examined the question better.

Comment: @Nitin It was, you can see the edit logs when you click on `edited xy mins ago` - unfortunately we're not high ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for you just need to divide the sums by the count.

```
$num = [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81];
$sum = 0;
$sum2 = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<count($num); $i++) {
    // regular sum
    $sum += $num[$i];
    // every other 
    if (($i % 2) != 0) {
        // for index 0, 2, 4, ... use == instead of !=
        $sum2 += $num[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. Your program outputs "Sum is 369 Sum of offset is 164"

Comment: It should output "Sum is 369 Sum of offset is 205"

Comment: Depends on if `every other number` starts with the first or second. (`1,21,41,61,81` or `11,31,51,71`)

Comment: By every other number do you mean 11, 31, 51, 71

Comment: I mean sum of everything is 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81

Comment: I mean sum of every other is 1, 21, 41, 61, 81

Comment: In either case, change `if (($i % 2) != 0) {` to `if (($i % 2) == 0) {` to change the start.

Comment: I got "Sum is 369 Sum of offset is 205"